# New Install of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

Had a series of problems. All my folders showed up LOCKED. Every single folder. I searched and tried a few solutions. Figured I would continue in the morning. Next morning booted to a strange screen. Could not get any where. I always have a back up on a thumb drive. So I restarted with a thumb drive to TRY/INSTALL Ubuntu. Did a reinstall. I could see only 128G of my 1TB drive. Same as before, Worked with that for a while. Went to save a file. Pop up said not enough space. Looked and looked for a solution to locate and mount the rest of my hard drive. Strange as it may seem, at times the rest of the drive showed up and other times it just didn’t show up on FILES, DISK, nor GPART. Finally one day it showed up. Set up partitions on GPART. Started adding files from the back up thump. Then a pop up came up saying something about some corrupted cylinders of spaces and the rest of the hard drive disappeared again. Called my computer guy and we agreed it appeared to be a hard drive at the end of its life.
Ordered a new hard drive and installed it. Started the laptop with the INSTALL UBUNTU thumb drive. I considered just a new install but had to click over to something else and take a look. Now here comes the question.
The drive choices under the view on SOMETHING ELSE showed the new 1TB drive empty, It also showed the 128G drive.

WDC PC SN520 SDAPMUW-128G-1101 (20290001)
128 GB (128,035,676,160 bytes)
GUID Partition Table

LVM2 Physical Volume (LVM2 001)
/dev/nvme0n1p2
Linux LVM

It showed /dev/nvme0n1p2 before I installed it. The view under Something Else also showed the thumb drive.
Question is, how did the  /dev/nvme0n1p2 show up before I installed it?

Other part of this post is, people are having the same problem with Ubuntu 22.04 install. Seeing 128G and missing the rest of the drive. DISKS should show it, In which case you need to set up partitions and mount them. Then they show up in FILES. It is easiest to add partitions using DISKS included in the install.